# Postgres case statement optimization

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance

Consider the following table where each columns has array of values

| g1 | g2 | g3 | ... | g20 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1,3,4 | 2,4,5 | 2,1,5 | ... | 27,4,5 |
| 1,8,4 | 3,6,18 | 8,4,5 | ... | 17,4,5 |
| 1,9,2 | 1,4,5 | 2,6,8 | ... | 7,4,30 |

Now, given an input array I want to fetch a row with the most number of intersections on all the columns. The maximum number of mismatches allowed for a candidate row is given as an input to the query.

My current query looks like this

```
select * from 
(select 
    (CASE when (g1 @> <input_arr1>) then 0 else 1 end +
     CASE when (g2 @> <input_arr2>) then 0 else 1 end +
     CASE when (g3 @> <input_arr3>) then 0 else 1 end 
     ...
     CASE when (g20 @> <input_arr4>) then 0 else 1) as mismatches
)as t where t.mismatches < 3;
```

Now given that we know maximum number of mismatches allowed, is there a way to stop further intersection operations once we know the mismatches reaches a maximum limit. For instance, if g1, g2, g3 does not intersects, we know that the `mismatches` is already 3, at this point, is there a way to avoid evaluating further case statements. I understand that the evaluation happens on select clause where we can't add conditional breaks. But just wondering if we can achieve this by query or table redesign.

Comment: Write a custom function in PL/pgSQL or another procedural language supported by PostgreSQL. In the function, you can implement short-circuiting logic to stop evaluating once the maximum number of mismatches is reached. This approach can be more efficient than a pure SQL query.

Comment: I think you have an X-Y problem. If you stored the arrays in a child table with each element in its own row, the query would become a lot simpler and probably execute faster. As your schema stands, I can't see an early exit, but if it's just a matter of performance, I don't think it will make much difference if you early exit or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your **case expression** into the where clause and then use a limit e.g:

```
WITH input_arrays AS (
    SELECT 
        array[1,3,4] AS input_arr1, 
        array[2,4,5] AS input_arr2, 
        array[1,8,4] AS input_arr3, 
        array[1,4,5] AS input_arr4
)
SELECT *
FROM your_data, input_arrays
WHERE 
    CASE WHEN g1  @> input_arr1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
  + CASE WHEN g2  @> input_arr2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
  + CASE WHEN g3  @> input_arr3 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
  + CASE WHEN g20 @> input_arr4 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END < 3
LIMIT 1;
```

See [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pqccRsO1)

However this may not achieve the desired "breakout"

```
QUERY PLAN
Limit  (cost=0.00..0.15 rows=1 width=256)
  ->  Seq Scan on your_data  (cost=0.00..25.60 rows=173 width=256)
        Filter: ((((CASE WHEN (g1 @> '{1,3,4}'::integer[]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + CASE WHEN (g2 @> '{2,4,5}'::integer[]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + CASE WHEN (g3 @> '{1,8,4}'::integer[]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) + CASE WHEN (g20 @> '{1,4,5}'::integer[]) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) < 3)
```

A procedural approach MIGHT work e.g:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_matching_row(
    input_arr1 INT[],
    input_arr2 INT[],
    input_arr3 INT[],
    input_arr4 INT[]
)
RETURNS INT AS $$
DECLARE
    result_row your_data%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR result_row IN SELECT * FROM your_data
    LOOP
        IF      (result_row.g1 @> input_arr1 AND
                result_row.g2 @> input_arr2 AND
                result_row.g3 @> input_arr3 AND
                result_row.g20 @> input_arr4) THEN
            CONTINUE; -- Skip to the next iteration if the condition is not met
        END IF;

        -- If the code reaches here, a row is a "mismatch"
        RETURN 1;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN 0; -- No row met the criteria
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

BUT a cursor approach might be slower than the query approach and you may lose flexibity.

see [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gavZBu98)

Instead of using a **case expression** in the where clause you could use boolean logic as follows. Note that each expression of this nature `g1   @> input_arr1` returns true or false, as you want mismatches then you need a false to become true so that can be achieved via  `NOT(g1   @> input_arr1)` - so if all 4 input arrays are unmatched then all predicates are true:

```
WITH input_arrays AS (
    SELECT 
        array[1,3,4] AS input_arr1, 
        array[2,4,5] AS input_arr2, 
        array[1,8,4] AS input_arr3, 
        array[1,4,5] AS input_arr4
)
SELECT *
FROM your_data, input_arrays
WHERE NOT(g1   @> input_arr1) 
  AND NOT(g2   @> input_arr2)
  AND NOT(g3   @> input_arr3)
  AND NOT(g20  @> input_arr4)
LIMIT 1;
```